# Group by, take first throws NotSupportedException in MongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to group a collection by `name` field and take the document with the maximum `score` using an aggregation pipeline.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetTopAsync(int limit, int offset)
{
    var x = await students
        .Aggregate(new AggregateOptions{AllowDiskUse = true})
        .Group(k => k.Class, g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Score).First())
        .Skip(offset)
        .Limit(limit)
        .ToListAsync();

    return x;
}
```

However, the above method throws the exception:

```
2020-11-10 10:57:27.3687|1.0.0.0|d3019991-db73-4a98-b331-ac6f00b49331|GlobalExceptionFilter|System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.AccumulatorBinder.GetAccumulatorArgument(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.AccumulatorBinder.TryGetAccumulatorTypeAndArgument(PipelineExpression node, AccumulatorType& accumulatorType, Expression& argument)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.AccumulatorBinder.VisitPipeline(PipelineExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.PipelineExpression.Accept(ExtensionExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.AccumulatorBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext bindingContext)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.EmbeddedPipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext parent)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.BindEmbeddedPipeline(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext context, Boolean isClientSideProjection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBindingContext.Bind(Expression node, Boolean isClientSideProjection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBindingContext.Bind(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.AggregateGroupTranslator.BindGroup[TKey,TDocument,TResult](PipelineBindingContext bindingContext, Expression`1 groupProjector, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, Expression keySelector)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.AggregateGroupTranslator.Translate[TKey,TDocument,TResult](Expression`1 idProjector, Expression`1 groupProjector, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, ExpressionTranslationOptions translationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.GroupExpressionProjection`3.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`2.<Group>b__0(IBsonSerializer`1 s, IBsonSerializerRegistry sr)
   at MongoDB.Driver.DelegatedPipelineStageDefinition`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 inputSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.AppendedStagePipelineDefinition`3.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 inputSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.AppendedStagePipelineDefinition`3.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 inputSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.AppendedStagePipelineDefinition`3.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 inputSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.AggregateAsync[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, PipelineDefinition`2 pipeline, AggregateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I guess the orderby/first methods are not implemented in the driver? What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @JMD I used `.Aggregate(PipelineDefinition<MyEntityCLass, BsonDocument>.Create(match, group, skip, take))` where `match`, `group`, etc defined using `BsonDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

With the MongoDB .net driver version 2.17 and later, it is possible to use `First()` as an accumulator in a `Group()` statement.

In the release notes for the MongoDB .net driver they state:

> Support for $topN and related accumulators in $group aggregation stage

Link to the release notes: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/what_is_new/

I have tested using `First()` as an accumulator, and it works with the updated driver. To use this feature, you will need to update your MongoDB .net driver to version 2.17.0 or later.

For older versions, `First()` is not supported as an accumulator in a `Group()` expression. I got the same exception mentioned in the question when using Version 2.10 of the MongoDB .net driver. Updating to the most recent version (2.19.1) resolved the issue for me.